# Ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> I'm trying to find the ring homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

What I think is the answer is two cases:

1) If $m \gt n $ there is no ring homomorphism.

2) Otherwise, the homomorphism sends each element $x$  in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $(x \bmod m)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Is this correct?

EDIT:
Part of the ring homomorphism definition is that 1 is sent to 1

Comment: This depends on whether your rings are required to have $1$.  We can have $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_n\to \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ via $\phi:[x]\mapsto[2x]$.

Comment: Should ring homomorphism map $1$ to $1$?

Comment: Excuse me, I edited the question. Yes, 1 is sent to 1 by definition.

Comment: You need some constrain on $m$ and $n$ so that $\phi(n)=0$.

Answer (score 8):

There exists a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$ if and only if $m$ divides $n$.

If $m$ divides $n$, let define: $$\Phi:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbb{Z}_n & \to & \mathbb{Z}_m\\
x\bmod n & \mapsto & x\bmod m
\end{array}\right..$$ 
$\Phi$ is a well defined ring homomorphism.

Assume there exists $\Phi$ a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}_m$, then one has : $$\Phi(0\bmod n)=\Phi(n\bmod n)=n\Phi(1\bmod n)=n\bmod m.$$
Since $\Phi(0\bmod n)=0\bmod m$, one has $n\bmod m=0$ and $m$ divides $n$.